# System.ServiceModel.Activation in mono 3.0.7

Tags: c#, mono

I'm trying to host a nuget feed on my ubuntu server, which has mono 3.07 installed from source.  I'm using the method described at [nuget.org](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds).  The project depends on `System.ServiceModel.Activation`, but it can't be found under mono.

According to [mono documentation](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.5&assembly=System.ServiceModel.Activation) the assembly has been implemented.  Do I need to install some other package to get it?

---

### Update

It turns out I was reading the wrong thing.  Mono doesn't currently support DataServices, and [nor does it plan to](http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development). After a lot of head-scratching, the best workaround I found was to [host a network file share on the Linux server](http://www.gordonml.co.uk/linux/hosting-a-nuget-feed-on-a-linux-server/) (blog post my own).

Comment: Have you added a project reference to `System.ServiceModel`?

Comment: Yes, and System.ServiceModel.Activation. It builds in windows under visual studio.

Comment: Have you added Copy Local = true?

Comment: No - but I'm building it with xbuild first to check that it's all going to work, and xbuild can't find that assembly.  It's not in my GAC either.

Comment: if in Windows it's present in the GAC, then maybe there's a bug in the "make install" phase of Mono where it's failing to install the assembly via gacutil or simply the call to gacutil is not there; I recommend that you investigate it and propose a pull request

Answer (score 0):

`System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll` has been implemented in Mono but not as a seperate assembly. It has been merged into [`System.ServiceModel.dll`](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.ServiceModel).