# Nuget.Server on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, nuget, local, nuget-server

I followed this steps to setup my own nuget server on local machine (Mac)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server

I got to step 6 and then when i click "here" it gives me the following error

```
System.Web.HttpException
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404.The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Details: Requested URL: /nuget/Packages
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00094] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/StaticFileHandler.cs:77 
  at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback callback, System.Object state) [0x0007f] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/DefaultHttpHandler.cs:101 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication+<Pipeline>d__225.MoveNext () [0x008d4] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1335 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-2017-02/bockbuild-2017-02/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:927
```

Please help

Comment: Here is a cross-platform server https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues in this approach.

1. Nuget.Server documentation mentions IIS as the web sever; IIS doesn't run on Mac OSX.
2. And, even if you end up using the [native web server](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/) of your operating system, you will need [WCF support in mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/) - which looks to be a work in progress.

Comment: A workaround would be to host a network file share on server as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642139/system-servicemodel-activation-in-mono-3-0-7). It talks about linux OS, but might apply to Mac OSX too.